# Where is exposed WEP key in auth mecanism?

Tags: wifi, wep

I know that WEP cipher is unsecure and offers no protection. It is said that in this authentication process, the WEP key is exposed,but, where, in what frame, is the key exposed? I know how the mecanism works, its based on a challenge text, but I dont know where exactly do you expose wep key. So far I know, you use the key to cipher the challenge text, but you dont see any key, you see something ciphered right? Hope you can help me.

Comment: you don't see the key, but it's computationally cheap to determine the key with brute-force once you observe the byproduct.

Comment: Ahhh Okey, thanks for your help, I didnt see the another question Limit, sorry

Comment: WEP is **not a cipher rather a Security Algorithm** designed as a protocol. It stands for `Wired Equivalent Privacy` & internally it uses `Stream Cipher RC4`. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy)